# Understanding how dynamic linking works on UNIX

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Consider we have the following situation:

- a program named `program` which depends dynamically on `libfoo.so`
- `libfoo.so` that depends on nothing (well, it depends on `libstdc++` and stuff but I guess we can omit that)

`program` runs perfectly.

Suddenly, `libfoo` codes changes, and some function now uses internally `func_bar()` a function that is provided by another library `libbar.so`.

`libfoo.so` is recompiled and now depends on `libbar.so`. `program` remains unchanged, it still depends only on `libfoo.so`.

Now when I execute `program` it complains that he can't find `func_bar()`.

Here are my questions:

- `libfoo.so` interface didn't change, only its implementation. Why does `program` have to **explicitely** link with `libbar.so` ?
- Isn't the dependency tree recursive ? I would have think that since `libfoo.so` depends on `libbar.so`, `libbar.so` would have been automatically added to the dependency list of `program`, **without** recompilation. However, `ldd program` shows that it is not the case.

It seems weird that one has to **recompile (relink) every binary** that depends on some library everytime that library's dependencies change. What solutions do I have here to prevent this ?

Comment: Can you post a minimal configuration that reproduces the problem? vitaut's comments following his post seem to describe the same process and does not arrive at the same problem. Maybe if you put simple steps, we could help with answering the question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem arises when you have not linked `libfoo.so` against `libbar`.  When you are compiling an executable, by default the linker will not let you leave undefined references.  However, when you're compiling a shared library, it *will* - and it will expect them to be satisfied at link time.  This is so that `libfoo` can use functions exported by `program` itself - when you try to run it, the dynamic linker is expecting `func_bar()` to be supplied by `program`.  The problem is illustrated like so:

(`foo.c` is selfcontained)

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=`pwd`
gcc -Wall -shared foo.c -o libfoo.so
gcc -Wall -L. p.c -lfoo -o p
```

At this point, `./p` runs correctly, as you would expect.  We then create `libbar.so` and modify `foo.c` to use it:

```
gcc -Wall -shared bar.c -o libbar.so
gcc -Wall -shared foo.c -o libfoo.so
```

At this point, `./p` gives the error you describe.  If we check `ldd libfoo.so`, we notice that it does *not* have a dependency on `libbar.so` - this is the error.  To correct the error, we must link `libfoo.so` correctly:

```
gcc -Wall -L. -lbar -shared foo.c -o libfoo.so
```

At this point, `./p` again runs correctly, and `ldd libfoo.so` shows a dependency on `libbar.so`.

Comment: You were right: I wasn't linking with `libbar.so`. Works like a charm now ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 9):

On Fedora dynamic linking is performed by ld-linux.so.2.
The dynamic linker use /etc/ld.so.cache and /etc/ld.so.preload to find library files.

Run ldconfig to tell the system where libfoo should look for libbar.

ldconfig looks in /lib, /usr/lib and any directory listed in /etc/ld.so.conf.
You can check which libraries a program uses with ldd.

More details are available on the manual pages for each command.

Here is an example of an application using shared libraries.  
 
Program.cc

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << func_foo(argv[i]) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#include <string>
std::string func_foo(std::string const &);
#endif
```

foo.cc

```
#include "foo.h"

std::string func_foo(std::string const &arg)
{
    return arg + "|" + __func__;
}
```

bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H
#include <string>
std::string func_bar();
#endif
```

bar.cc

```
#include "bar.h"

std::string func_bar()
{
    return __func__;
}
```

Build with libfoo.so as a shared library.  
g++ -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -shared foo.cc -o libfoo.so  
g++ -lfoo -L./ -Wall -Wextra program.cc foo.h -o program  
ldd program  
        ...  
        libfoo.so => not found

Update /etc/ld.so.cache  
sudo ldconfig /home/tobias/projects/stubs/so/

ldd shows that the dynamic linker finds libfoo.so  
ldd program  
        ...  
        libfoo.so => /home/tobias/projects/stubs/so/libfoo.so (0x00007f0bb9f15000)

Add a call to libbar.so in libfoo.so  
New foo.cc

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

std::string func_foo(std::string const &arg)
{
    return arg + "|" + __func__ + "|" + func_bar();
}
```

Build libbar.so and rebuild libfoo.so  
g++ -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -shared bar.cc -o libbar.so  
g++ -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -shared libbar.so foo.cc -o libfoo.so  
ldd libfoo.so  
        ...  
        libbar.so => not found

ldd program  
        ...  
        libfoo.so => /home/tobias/projects/stubs/so/libfoo.so (0x00007f49236c7000)  
        libbar.so => not found  
This shows that the dynamic linker still finds libfoo.so but not libbar.so  
Again update /etc/ld.so.cache and recheck.  
sudo ldconfig /home/tobias/projects/stubs/so/  
ldd libfoo.so  
        ...  
        libbar.so => /home/tobias/projects/stubs/so/libbar.so (0x00007f935e0bd000)

ldd program  
        ...  
        libfoo.so => /home/tobias/projects/stubs/so/libfoo.so (0x00007f2be4f11000)  
        libbar.so => /home/tobias/projects/stubs/so/libbar.so (0x00007f2be4d0e000)

Both libfoo.so and libbar.so are found.

Note this last step have no effect on the application program.
If you are really strict running ldconfig is kind of relinking.
Weird or not the linker need to know the dependencies of the libraries it links.
There are a lot of other ways to implement this but this was chosen.

Answer (score 2):

You did not give any system information, are you using glibc? If yes what is the output of this command:

LD_DEBUG=files   program

Also check ["How to write shared (ELF) libraries"](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)(pdf) (whether you are using glibc or not)

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't have to link with libbar.so.

I think that the problem is caused by failing to specify `libbar.so` as a dependency of `libfoo.so` when building the later.
I am not sure what build system are you using but in CMake it can be done as follows:

```
add_library(bar SHARED bar.c)

add_library(foo SHARED foo.c)
target_link_libraries(foo bar)

add_executable(program program.c)
target_link_libraries(program foo)
```

As you can see `program` is linked only with `foo` (`libfoo.so`) and `foo` only with `bar` (`libbar.so`).

Or it may be that `libbar.so` can't be found. Try to specify the path to its directory in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The question is what CMake does behind the scenes, it might be smart enough to build the right link command for program

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger: Good question. I thought about this and did some experiments (building `program` while `foo` didn't have a link to `bar`, then building `foo` and `bar`, but not `program`) and it worked. So the magic from cmake side seems unlikely in this case, although it is smart indeed =).

Comment: Does this really answer the question? Of course, linking `libbar` in with `libfoo` and *then* linking with `program` is going to work, independantly of the build system. However, if `program` is linked with `libfoo` and then `libfoo` is updated to link with `libbar` this might not be the case. If your CMake script, it is clear that `program` relinks with `libfoo` if `libfoo` changes to link with `libbar` without any magic.

Comment: Try the following test: write 2 CMake scripts, one that builds `program` by linking it with `libfoo` and one that builds `libfoo`. Proceed as OP asked: build `libfoo`, then build `program` and run the test. Then, change `libfoo` to link with `libbar`, re-build `libfoo` but don't rebuild `program`. Try to see if it still works.

Comment: @André Caron: Sorry if it was not clear from my answer, but I did almost exactly what you described in the last post.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be the case unless something about the bar_func *symbol* changed. Use the "nm" command to get a dump of the symbols in both your program, and the shared object - see if there is a mismatch and why.

Comment: My read of the question is that the change in `bar_func()` is that previously it was not used, but now it is used.